# Make Windows remember which process to suspend

Tags: windows-10, process, process-hacker

I have some process that I want to be suspended every time the systems boots, but I don't want to disable it. I tried to find some options in Resource Monitor, Process Explorer, Process Hacker, but found nothing. The name of the process is sppsvc.exe and I want my PC to remember that whenever it sees a process with that name to suspend it.

Comment: Why don't you want to disable it. seems as though that is what you are describing.

Comment: Or perhaps either a `automatic (delayed start)` or `manual` from `service.msc` from the applicable service properties.

Comment: Trust me, I tried many solutions and it turns out that the best one is to run it and suspend it. That way it won't occupy CPU every 40 seconds and my Windows will think it's activated, and, also, i can still use MS Office. If I disable it I can't use office

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Mircosoft sysinternals pssuspend](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pssuspend).

You can create a scheduled task at logon to invoke this, or create a task to run every x minutes if there are new processes spawned. When creating the task make sure to specify that it runs with highest privileges.

`C:\yourpath\pssuspend64.exe sppsvc.exe`

However, the exe you are talking about is a windows service called `Software Protection`, which can be disabled in the services MSC.

Comment: Can you please explain it with more steps. I tried (really tried) but I don't know how to use pssuspend. pleeeeeeeeeeeeeease pliz pliz pliz pliz

Comment: pliz pliz pliz pliz

Answer (score 1):

Download that [PsSuspend thing](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pssuspend).
Extract and put the folder somewhere safe.

Go to task scheduler, click "create basic task" on right hand side.
Name it w/e for trigger, set it to when computer starts.

"Action" is "start a program".
Navigate to `pssuspend.exe` in the folder that you just downloaded.
Add argument `sppsvc.exe` and finish.

Then scroll down the list of tasks in the middle of scheduler and find what you just made and double click it to pop out a new window. Check the box that says "run with highest privileges".

Click triggers at the top and double click at startup.
Check "delay task for" and put in some amount of minutes. I put in 4 minutes.

This will make a schedule that will suspend `sppsvc.exe` a couple of minutes after startup. If you don't create a delay, it won't work, because `sppsvc.exe` needs time to startup before you can suspend it.