# Using PsSuspender to suspend a process by a task

Tags: process, windows-task-scheduler, suspend

Can somebody explain me how to set a task (in Task Scheduler) to run a command. Okay, I know nothing about this, but I couldn't find any tutorial. So, I don't know:

1. How to install PsSuspend
2. How to use PsSuspend
3. How to pronounce PsSuspend

And, then I want to put it into a task that would run and try to suspend a specific program (specified by process's name). Can you please explain me how to accomplish the previous, step by step?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Do you mention the task? You should learn [Schtasks command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725744(v=ws.11).aspx) and [PSsuspen command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pssuspend#using-pssuspend).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming from your [previous post](https://superuser.com/questions/1248051/make-windows-remember-which-process-to-suspend) that you're trying to suspend `sppsvc.exe` upon logon.

---

- First start off downloading PsTools from [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pstools)
- PsTools isn't something that needs to be installed per se. You just extract the zipped folder anywhere you want, although generally it's a good idea to put it in a folder path set in your Environmental Variables so you can easily run it from the command line in the future without needing to CD into its specific directory. A good place to copy the pstools folder that you unzipped is into `C:\Windows`
- Next open up **Task Scheduler** by going to **Start Menu** > Type out **Task Scheduler** and hit **Enter**
- In the Task Scheduler window click on **Action** at the top left corner and then select **Create Task**

[image: open Task Scheduler]

- Give your task a name, and a brief description if you want
- Towards the bottom look for the **Run with highest privileges** checkbox and select it
- Underneath that where it says **Configure for** choose your version of Windows

[image: name task]

- Now go to the **Triggers** tab and click on **New** towards the bottom
- In the **Begin the task:** dropdown menu select **At log on**
- Click **OK** to close out of that window

[image: setting triggers]

- Now back at the **Create Task** window go to the **Actions** tab and click on **New** towards the bottom
- Under **Program/script** click on **Browse**
- Navigate to where you put the `PSTools` folder. In this example it is located at `C:\Windows\PSTools`
- Select the file named `pssuspend64.exe` and then click on **Open**
- In the **Add arguments(optional)** field type in `sppsvc.exe`  (if my earlier assumption is correct that that's the process you're trying to suspend at logon
- Click **OK** to exit that window

[image: choose program to run]

- Now click **OK** again to exit out of the **Create Task** window and you're done.
- Log off your PC and log back in and you'll see that sppsvc.exe is suspended in **Task Manager**

Comment: You missed a comma :) THANK YOU VERY VERY MUCH FOR SUCH A LONG AND DETAILED ANSWER! I did exactly how you said and it all worked! You were right about my previous post: that's the process that were annoying me. Now it's gone - no more CPU wasteage! Thank you for your time and effort to make this!